# Bluetooth headset with more than 1 control button

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to design an application that runs on a smartphone with a bluetooth headset (for voice), with more than one control button.  I have researched online and it seems to me that I need to use one of the bluetooth profiles and the closest is the Headset profile.  That profile only describes one button and it is for obtaining and ending a connection only.  So, can anyone tell me what should I do? What options do I have? Any pointer will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work for CSR, we produce Bluetooth chips (as well as pretty much every other Radio on a chip technology).

We produce a software development kit for BlueCore system on a chip applications that would allow you to customise an Audio headset app (Hands Free Profile, Headset Profile, etc). Our BlueCore chips have multiple IO pins, how many are buttons and what they do depends on how you want to hook 'em up.

Also, that single button can be programmed to do a lot of stuff - press once to answer a call/terminate a call. Hold for 2-seconds to start connecting/pairing with a phone. Hold for 4-seconds to power down.

If there are volume up/down buttons you could use button combinations to trigger an action e.g volume-up and main button held at the same time.

http://www.csr.com

Broadcom make Bluetooth chips too but I don't know anything about their dev kits.

Comment: Hi Pev, thanks for your answer.  It is very helpful.  What if the target devices are iPhone and Android phone.  I suppose I don't program for a particular chipset as the OS has a very good abstraction layer.

Comment: Android is (apparently) pretty straight forward but for iPhone, anything other than standard Headset profile, requires an authentication chip. Apple don't play well with others.

Comment: Thanks, Pev.  I have one question.  For programming the button and adding new buttons, they should be done in which layer? I have researched on www.bluetooth.com and org, and they have a lot of content.  I'd appreciate

Comment: Adding additional button functionality would be application specific and not part of a profile as such. To communicate associated events you would probably which to use an RFCOMM channel with an application specific UUID to identify it. Bluetooth on-chip application programming is a small world - not much help on-line unless you have access to company specific support channels.

Comment: @simonPeverett Hello, I am learning how to program CSR's Bluecore chip (specifically 8675, both kalimba and VM) and I was wondering if you could point me to some good online discussion forums on bluecore programming. I have some questions which I am sure someone more experienced with the chip would be able to answer for me, but I am having a very hard time finding good online resources. The forums provided by CSR (and Qualcomm) are not very helpful, as their moderators insist that the forum is not for discussions about the Bluecore series of chips.

Comment: I know how to write programs for the XAP based VM as well as kalimba so I am not a complete beginner, but I feel that discussing specific programming problems with someone more experienced with the chip would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my input to Pev's comments:

- CSR's development kits are very easy to use, however you will not be able to do everything you want with just one. For example there is only one development kit that works with Apple products.
- CSR support is limited to the development kit you purchase (which is fair IMO).
- CSR likes big companies more than hobbyists (which is perfectly understandable).
- You still have to design your own embedded product afterwards, and go through a certification process. This is a bit tricky if you use CSR chips, because not many manufacturers have the technology required to plant them (they have a lot of pins in ball grid array design technology if I am not mistaken).

Best way to go about it is to buy the CSR development board for getting a start.

Then if you want more development boards for testing you can buy programmable evaluation boards sporting CSR chips from 3rd party companies - they can be 20$-50$ a pop (plus the programmer 100$ or something).